# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, list, file

```
view_class = input("What class score would you like to view?")
view_class = str(view_class) + ".txt"
```

If I enter "1" (r any other number), the error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.txt'
```

:(

This is python idle 3.4.2

```
def alphabetical():
    global view_class, name, name_scores, class_number, score
    view_class = input("What class score would you like to view?")
    view_class = str(view_class) + ".txt"
    class_number = view_class
    with open(class_number, "r") as file: #1
        file.seek() #2
        scores = file.readlines() #3

    with open(class_number) as file:
        for name in sorted(name_scores): #16
            print(name, '-', name_scores[name]) #17

alphabetical()
```

EDIT: HERE IS THE SUBSEQUENT CODE
I do not think that the problem is with the file directory because I have retrieved data from the same text file elsewhere, and the file directory was not needed

Comment: Is there any code following after these two lines? An open command by any chance?

Comment: Is there a file `1.txt` in your current working directory?

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean by an open command?

Comment: Yes! @Kenney but it has been previously created from another function

Comment: The error seems not to be caused by the code you provided, but maybe by a subsequent statement; are you trying to access view_class afterwards?

Comment: I have updated the code, please could you have a look, @Pachelbel

Comment: Do you really need the seek()? seek() actually requires an offset to locate to within the file, afaik. Also the second open seems not to be required, since you're not reading from the file. How are you starting the script, from the command line? If you use relative paths, it is crucial from where you invoke it, i.e., which is the current directory when you invoke python(3).exe.

Comment: @Pachelbel ok i have removed it, but the same error occurs

Comment: Could you state exactly how you invoke the script? From the commandline? Something like "C:\Projects\> Python.exe my_script.py" ?

Comment: Sorry, @Pachelbel I don't understand what you mean? how do i find that out?

Comment: Ok, we can also try this: could you put `import os` right at the beginning of your script and add the line `print('The current directory is: %s' % os.getcwd())` right before the `with` statement that tries to open the file? This directory should be the one where your 1.txt is located in. Is it?

Comment: Yes! It prints the file directory of the FOLDER that the file is stored within, what does this mean? It all seems correct?

Comment: Really strange. One more attempt from my side: Could you add `print('The files in there: %s' % os.listdir(os.getcwd()))` also before the `with` statement? If "1.txt" is in the outputted list, we might need your complete script ...

Comment: @Pachelbel it printed '1.txt.txt'

Comment: @Pachelbel I think because the file is called '1.txt' and then plus the '.txt' for the text file which is why it is double

Comment: :) I think if you remove the additional .txt you should be a step further. If you create the file in your script also, there might be the error that you append .txt twice. Windows by default does not show the file extensions if you look at files e.g. in the Explorer window.

Comment: I removed the additional txt, but the same error, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1'

Comment: @Pachelbel thank you so much for your help, view_class = str(view_class) + ".txt" + ".txt", I added an extra .txt to match the file name

Comment: @Pachelbel how can i accept your answer on here?

Comment: I think it's not possible since it's a comment, but never mind. Have fun coding!

Comment: A side note: view_class = str(view_class) + ".txt" + ".txt", this looks a little bit strange :) maybe you consider changing other parts of your script such that you do not need the double ".txt".

Answer (score 0):

You need to give file location too. Suppose your file is in D:\folder1\1.txt

then the code should be following

```
str_path = "D:\\folder1\\"
view_class = input("What class score would you like to view?")
view_class = str_path + str(view_class) + ".txt"
```

Comment: but I have created and retrieved data from the same text file earlier on in the code, and I didn't have to give the file location?